# Magento 2 magic methods phpunit tests

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I've started learning and at the same time writing tests for my Magento 2 custom development. Not a ride in the park. It feels like digging a pit in the sand sometimes. I got to the point where I need to test something like:

```
$payment->setPaymentReminderSendStatus(true)->save();
```

Writing something like below won't work.

```
$this->orderPaymentMockSend->expects($this->once())
    ->method('setPaymentReminderSendStatus')
    ->with($paymentReminderSentStatus)
    ->willReturnSelf()
;
```

It will fail with the message: *Trying to configure method setPaymentReminderSendStatus which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static*, which is true because the setters and getters are handled by `\Magento\Framework\DataObject::__call` magic method.

A colleague suggested mocking the payment object like below, but to me it feels a bit like hardcoding.

```
$this->orderPaymentMockSend = $this->getMockBuilder(Payment::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['setPaymentReminderSendStatus'])
    ->getMock()
;
```

I'm also looking at maybe mocking the \Magento\Framework\DataObject object to be able to use the __call method (I don't if this is even possible or if I'm overthinking it).

What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to use magic methods :

```
    /** Mock Customer */
    //Add a magic method to the list of mocked class methods
    $methods = \array_merge(
        \get_class_methods(Customer::class),
        ['getCustomerType']
    );

    $this->customerModelMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Customer::class)
        ->setMethods($methods)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    //Now I can mock my magic method !
    $this->customerModelMock->expects(static::any())
        ->method('getCustomerType')
        ->willReturn('professional');
```

Comment: this looks pretty much the same with what I'm already doing

Answer (score 0):

If your magic function **does not** have any parameters do the following

```
$map = [
    ['getProductLabel', [], 'Some Label']
];

/**
getProductLabel is function name,
[] is parameter being passed (in this case empty),
'Some Label' is the return
*/

$mock->method('__call')
      ->willReturnMap($map);
```

If your magic function **has parameters** do the following

```
$map = [
    ['setShippingRates', [true], 'some return'],
];
$mock->method('__call')->willReturnMap($map);

/**
setShippingRates is the function name,
[true] is parameter being passed (1 parameter with value true),
'some return' is the return
*/
```

The following article explains the steps in detail
http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/phpunit-magento-magic-functions.php

I hope that helps